# UIButton: why are rounded corners visible?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton whose type is set to 'custom' in IB. In code, the button is formatted like so:

```
self.btnScan.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.btnScan.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.btnScan.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
self.btnScan.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0f;
```

In the IOS-Simulator it is displayed correctly, but when I test on the device (iPad 2), there are light grey rounded corners in addition to the actual black non-rounded border. 
See pictures:

original size: [image: corners]

enlarged size: [image: corners enlarged]

I also tried

```
[self.btnScan.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

without success.

How can I eliminate those grey rounded corners? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: What could be the reason for this error only appearing on the device and not in simulator. I also tried xCode clean and re-installing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, I'm sure your suggestions are working in 99,99% of all cases. But in my special case it seems that xCode was messing things up completely.

I restarted xCode several times, double checked all settings (e.g. outlets) in IB and in code. I cleaned the project. I removed the app from the iPad and reinstalled it. I even created some new buttons in the xib, which all had the same problem.

The only thing that helped in the end was to delete the xib and re-creating it from scratch. 
Even tough this might not be the most beautiful solution, it solved the problem. Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it's still the standard `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` . There is something wrong with the initalization. Double check IB and your initalization code. If the button is custom, you would not see anything inside.

If it appears only on the device, perhaps there is an old nib file on the device. Remove the app, then do a clean in Xcode, then reinstall.

Comment: I triple checked IB. The button type is 'custom' even after clean and restart of xCode. In IB, I see an empty, clean button without border or background or whatever. I also removed the app from the iPad again and re-compiled it. Still the same. Slowly becoming desperate...

Comment: Did you check the outlets? Did you create another button next to it? Did you comment out all custom code in the viewController for testing?

Comment: once check in your code may be programatically you are changing button type.

Answer (score 0):

This is working proper at my end.So i think you are going to do wrong in either your code or xib

See in this image.

[image]

Comment: [self.btnScan setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score -1):

```
button.opaque = NO;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Didn't see the uibutton custom... Hope this helps...

Try this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Like I said, the buttonType is set to custom in IB. I cannot set this in code because it's a readonly property.